# Searching images files with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:58] "GET /media/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:58] "GET /media/js/fancybox/fancybox-x.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:59] "GET /media/js/fancybox/fancybox-y.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:59] "GET /media/js/fancybox/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:59] "GET /ajax/pages/erlebnisse/ HTTP/1.1" 200 563
[22/Nov/2011 12:58:00] "GET /erlebnisse/alle-erlebnisse/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17114
```

I want to use regular expressions to get all the image files (.gif, .jpg, .png) that appear here. So the result from the text above should be:

```
['fancybox-x.png', 'fancybox-y.png', 'blank.gif']
```

What I did was:

```
re.findall('\w+\.(jpg|gif|png)', f.read())
```

So the pattern is:

> 1 or more word-characters `(\w+)` followed by a dot `(\.)` and then 'jpg', 'gif' or 'png' `(jpg|gif|png)`.

This actually works, but confuses the content of the parentheses (which I'm using only for "grouping") as a `group(1)`, so the result is:

```
['png', 'png', 'gif']
```

With is right, but incomplete. In other words, I'm asking, **how can I make `re.findall()` distinguish between "grouping" parentheses and parentheses to assign groups?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for non-capturing version of regular parentheses `(?:...)`. The description is available in the [re module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

```
s ='''[22/Nov/2011 12:57:58] "GET /media/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:58] "GET /media/js/fancybox/fancybox-x.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:59] "GET /media/js/fancybox/fancybox-y.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:59] "GET /media/js/fancybox/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[22/Nov/2011 12:57:59] "GET /ajax/pages/erlebnisse/ HTTP/1.1" 200 563
[22/Nov/2011 12:58:00] "GET /erlebnisse/alle-erlebnisse/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17114'''

import re

for m in re.findall('([-\w]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png))', s):
    print m
```

Comment: I actually liked more your answer without the code.. made me feel like a newbie :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can just add another pair of parentheses, and put ?: for the inner one

```
re.findall('/([^/]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png))', f.read())
```

Note that `\w` won't match "-", so I would suggest `[^/]+`

Comment: you're right about the "-". What's the `[^/]+` for? same as `[\w-]+`?

Comment: @julio.alegria , `[^/]` will match all characters other than "/".

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the entire match you should be able to find it in group 0, otherwise you can add extra parentheses if you're looking for another part of the string.

Comment: `re.findall()` returs a list, so there's no group 0

Comment: if you have multiple groups in your re, findall returns a list of tuples, so you could do `["".join(groups) for groups in re.findall('(\w+\.)(gif|png|jpg)', my_data)]` -- note the new parenths around `\w+\.` -- accepted answer is obviously a better solution here but i can see this being potentially useful.